# How to get values at individual points after normalization by matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, normalization

Following code generates a hexbin plot after normalizing data between the defined range.

```
from matplotlib.cm import viridis_r as glocmap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.uniform(1.0, 10, size=(100,2))

ax1 plt.hexbin(data[:,0], data[:,1], bins=None,gridsize=(20,15), cmap=glocmap,
           vmin=0, vmax=100, alpha=0.75, mincnt=1.0)

cb = plt.colorbar(label='count')
cb.set_label('COUNT',size=20)
cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=20) 
cb.set_alpha(1)

ax1.get_array()   #has length of 95
ax1._offsets       #2D array array of length 95
```

I want to know 'count value' at every 'coordinate value' from data. The axis instance an attribute called '_offsets' which when plotted produce same plot as the one with plt.hexbin so I thought that may be the coordinate values, but those values are slightly different from the values in 'data'.
By coordinate I mean values of x and y axis.

**EDIT**: As suggested in comments, applying .get_array() on axis instance gives array whose length (95) is equal to length of ._offsets attribute. My objective is to find 'counts' at corresponding points from 'data'. e.g. what will be 'count' value at data[0]?

[image: hexbin plot from python code]

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The individual point in the image has a 'count' value. I want to know that value. To be more precise, I want to know which point (from 'data') carries what count value?

Comment: The documenation says "Returns 
a PolyCollection instance; use PolyCollection.get_array on this to get the counts in each hexagon." Can you edit the question to show in how far this is not what you want?

Answer (score 2):

The `PolyCollection`'s `.get_array()` method will return the number of counts for each hexagon. The `.get_offsets()` method will return the center of each hexagon.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.uniform(1.0, 10, size=(50,2))

pc = plt.hexbin(data[:,0], data[:,1], bins=None,gridsize=(7,4), cmap="viridis_r",
                vmin=0, vmax=5, mincnt=1.0)

cb = plt.colorbar(label='count')
cb.set_label('COUNT',size=20)
cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=20) 
cb.set_alpha(1)

counts = pc.get_array() 
positions = pc.get_offsets() 

print(counts[:10])
print(positions[:10])

for c, (x,y) in zip(counts[:10],positions[:10]):
    plt.text(x,y,"{:d}".format(int(c)), ha="center", va="center")

plt.show()
```

will print

```
[1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 1. 2. 1. 3.]
[[1.04969905 1.41805371]
 [1.04969905 3.53403589]
 [1.04969905 7.76600025]
 [1.04969905 9.88198243]
 [2.28920799 5.65001807]
 [2.28920799 7.76600025]
 [2.28920799 9.88198243]
 [3.52871693 1.41805371]
 [3.52871693 3.53403589]
 [3.52871693 5.65001807]]
```

and show

[image]

For example the first hexagon is centered at `x=1.04969905, y=1.41805371` and has one point in it (count==1). The tenth hexagon is centered at `x=3.52871693, y=5.65001807` and has 3 points in it (count==3).

Comment: I was expecting values in 'positions' to be from 'data', but they are not although they lie in the same range as the values in 'data'. My original objective was to get 'counts' at values in 'data'. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think I understand what "get 'counts' at values in 'data'" is supposed to mean. Say you have data at `[0.9, 0.95]` and `[1.1,1.05]` and they end up in a hexagonal bin centered at `[1,1]`, what is the desired outcome of "'counts' at values in 'data'"?