# Difficulty Zooming In on a Specific Hexbin in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently working on a data visualization task using matplotlib, specifically a hexbin plot. My goal is to create a figure that displays the overall distribution of my data and then zoom in on a specific hexbin to show the underlying data in that particular region.

I have successfully created a hexbin plot using the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate random data
np.random.seed(42)
x = np.random.randn(1000)
y = np.random.randn(1000)

# Create hexbin plot
plt.hexbin(x, y, gridsize=25, cmap='viridis')

# Add labels and title
plt.xlabel('X-axis')
plt.ylabel('Y-axis')
plt.title('Hexbin Plot')

# Add a colorbar
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.set_label('Count')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

[image: Output of the code above]

Now, I'm facing challenges in zooming in on a specific hexbin and displaying the underlying data within that bin. Despite extensive research and coding, I couldn't find a direct solution in the documentation.

Any help or guidance on how to achieve this specific zoom functionality would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See e.g. [How to get values at individual points after normalization by matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52752826) to find the counts and the centers of each bin.  You can zoom in via setting the xlim and ylim close to the center of the desired bin.  Finding you which original data belongs to which bin seems a bit more complicated.